# How to pass argument object variable from behat.yml to FeatureContext.php constructor?

Tags: drupal-8, behat

In my behat.yml contexts I need to pass an argument object variable to the FeatureContext.php constructor method.

In my behat.yml file, I can't instantiate an instance of the class required by the constructor in FeatureContext.php.

When I ran the Behat test, it show an error said I passed in a "String" but require instance of a class FourZeroFour

Here's my behat.yml

```
local:
  suites:
    default:
      paths:
        # Set features to repo root so that .feature files belonging to contrib
        # modules, themes, and profiles can be discovered.
        features: /var/www/mywebsite
        bootstrap: /var/www/mywebsite/tests/behat/features/bootstrap
      contexts:
        - Drupal\FeatureContext: 
          fourZeroFour: FourZeroFour
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
  extensions:
```

Here's my constructor method in FeatureContext.php

```
/**
 * FeatureContext class defines custom step definitions for Behat.
 */
class FeatureContext extends PageObjectContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext {

  private $fourZeroFour;

  public function __construct(FourZeroFour $fourZeroFour) {
    $this->fourZeroFour = $fourZeroFour;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are:

- `FeatureContext` should extend `MinkContext` or another context from Drupal that extends `MinkContext` if any(maybe `MinkContext` from drupal).
- the `yml` file should load `MinkContext` only once, add only the class that extends `MinkContext` directly of trough another class.
  For example: if FeatureContext extends MinkContext or another class that extends MinkContext, then in the yml you can only add `FeatureContext`
- for page objects use injecting so that you can benefit of autocomplete in your ide
- regarding the constructor, that seems to be a page object, you can importing with `use`